# Convert Base64 to original image path

Tags: php, base64

I'm using the following code to encode my image path. I want to know if it is safe or someone can decode the original file path from encoded string?

```
$imagedata = file_get_contents("ab/test.png");
$base64 = base64_encode($imagedata);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$base64.'" />';
```

also do i have to use data:image/jpeg or png or gif or any extension would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can decode the data, but can't know what the original filename was. The encoded data contains just the image data, not its **meta**-data (as in filename, mime-type -not directly-, inode, etc).

As per your second question: you must use the proper MIME type that matches the data, otherwise the browser/client won't understand its contents.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the file contents into a Base64 encoded string, so no, they can not get the path because you only provide the contents.

Answer (score 0):

If by "safe" you mean reversible then no, it is not safe.

Base64 encodes data which can be decoded easily with base64_decode. Someone would be able to decode your base64 data into the original image.